# Wordpress included custom PHP page but use styling of current theme?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a number of individual page with custom php and javascript that I need to use in a wordpress site.

I had read one way to do this would be to create a custom template and 'include' the page, this works, but I dont get the basic styling of a Wordpress generated page.

eg:

page-testa-php.php (simple example) :

```
<?php
echo "This is a line of my content!";
?>
```

Published page uses template below:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: TestA
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages and that
 * other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a different template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content" class="main-content">

<?php
    if ( is_front_page() && twentyfourteen_has_featured_posts() ) {
        // Include the featured content template.
        get_template_part( 'featured-content' );
    }
?>
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

            <?php
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    // Include the page content template.
                    get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );

                    // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                    if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                        comments_template();
                    }
                endwhile;

                include('page-testa-php.php');

            ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->

    </div><!-- #primary -->
    <?php get_sidebar( 'content' ); ?>
</div><!-- #main-content -->

<?php

get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

The text 'This is a line of my content!' does show in the correct area of the page, but I can already see it is not subject to the styling that would occur if I added the text directly into the page via the Wordpress editor.

(it has no indenting and is hard left against the left hand sidebar for example)

I was hoping to be able to add styling markup in my own code like 'text-align: center;' etc. but have that working within the control of the themes responsiveness design. Is this possible?

Is it just that I have the 'include' in the wrong place in the template file?, or that I need some basic markup in my included file to 'access' the styling of my theme? 
I can't find anything that documents the structure of a Wordpress page that tells me what classes I would need (or can) reference in source page.

Comment: As long as you use the proper HTML-codes IN YOUR INCLUDED FILE, the styling will work just fine.  For the example you provided, what you're including is just plain text - no HTML tags at all, so of course it won't have any style attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using some formatting tags, e.g. p, h3, etc. Is it still not pulling your theme styles?

Comment: When I added <p> tags (comparing with a page generated within Wordpress) it made no difference (ie indent level was missing) - but I think I was missing was the <div class="entry-content"> in my source file, as including this appears to have addressed the issue. This is why I thought I might have been 'including in the wrong place' because I wasn't sure I was in the correct div. I am not sure whether this is the complete fix as I am not sure on the correct anatomy of a page.

Comment: This should be the answer. Your theme is going to have typographical style properties as well as styles applied to certain id and class names. If your content does not contain any of those that are in your theme's CSS, any global styles (e.g. body) or lack thereof, will be the default. As far as the include, the browser will treat the markup like you pasted it into the page. It will not decipher. That all happens on the server. Moreover, if you aren't seeing styles applied to your additional markup, it's because you are missing markup that's found in your theme css. It's that simple.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to Wordpress and HTML/CSS
I thought a Wordpress theme might have some standard classes like "post-title", "post-content-body" etc.
I thought the position of the include was significant because for instance, if I had included immediately after the '<div id="primary" class="content-area">' (in the template file) it would be subject to the default styling for class="content-area", but if I included it after the </div>, it would not?

Comment: As I was just trying to get the text to appear within a certain section of the page (as if I had created a post through the Wordpress GUI), I thought the answer might have been something like "Your theme will be using a class 'xyz' for the basic post body text formatting, so either create a div with class 'xyz' before your include statement in the template file, or reference class 'xyz' in your source." or "the text from your source file needs to be in the div with id 'abc' to follow your themes styling for post body text" (assuming there was some standards across themes).